# Does bitlocker encrypt data at shutdown/restart?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, bitlocker

I am using Windows 10 Pro on a SSD drive.

I would like to know when bitlocker encrypt data.

For example if encryption happen at shutdown/restart or when actually creating or modifying file in the OS working.

Basically I am interested to understand if it can slow down my machine only at reboot/shutdown and not when working with files.

Comment: If it would only happen at start/shutdown it would take ages. If you have somewhat current hardware you probably won't notice the impact.

Comment: Neither, Data is encrypted when Bitlocker is enabled, and accessible when the passcode is provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitlocker encrypts the data as it's written and decrypts as it's read. This is not as slow as it might seem as most CPUs have dedicated silicon to speed up AES encryption/decryption.